# Iterating over array of objects javascript - odd behaviour?

Tags: javascript

```
var myArr = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}];

for (var item in myArr) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Item returns the key (ex: 0, 1) instead of the object itself. Why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Douglas Crockford recommends in [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/)  to avoid using the `for in` statement.

If you use `for in` to loop over property names in an object, the ***results are not ordered***.

The `for in` loop is best for iterating over **name-value** pairs, and the `for each` loop best for iterating over values i.e arrays.

E.g,

```
var o = {'name':'Batman', 'age':33, 'city':'Gotham City'};
   for (var p in o) {
        console.log(p+': '+o[p]);
    }
```

There’s no way we can get the property name if we were to use the For Each Loop for the above object.

---

**Note :**

1. The *For in* Loop is best for name-value pairs.
2. The *For Each* Loop is best for iterable values. Eg: arrays, and objects if you are not interested in the name of the property.

Comment: Thanks. I've been meaning to read that book. I had no idea of the existence of a 'for each' loop - is this supported by all major browsers?

Comment: @Andy: The [`for each ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) statement is an extension only available in Mozilla based implementations, (it won't work on other browsers). When working with arrays, just use any sequential loop... [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays/4261096#4261096).

Comment: It's worth noting that *for..in* is useful for sparse arrays provided inhertied enumerable properties are dealt with (e.g. a *hasOwnProperty* test) and order is not important.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as the answer as it works for simple arrays, not arrays of objects

Comment: This answer is outdated. The new and vastly improved way to achieve this (with ECMAScript 6) is with a `for...of` loop. See the answer below.

Answer (score 22):

Javascript `for`..`in` loops always return the index/name, not the value. To get what you want, you should use:

```
var myArr = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}];

for (var index in myArr) {
    console.log( myArr[index] );
}
```

However, as said before, the `for`..`in` statement should be use with caution, and it is not intended to be used with an array. You should use a `for` loop instead

```
var myArr = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}];

for( var i=0, l=myArr.length; i<l; i++ ) {
    console.log( myArr[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `for` ... `in` loop iterates over the keys (properties) of an object.
It is not intended to be used for arrays.

It will also iterate over properties inherited from the object's `prototype`.

Comment: But it is not a hashmap/key-value pair. If I did a for...in loop with ['a','b','c'] or [1,2,3] it would return the value and not the index. EDIT: just saw your update. I'll just iterate using a regular for loop then. Thanks!

Comment: @andy: Wrong; it will return the index.  Arrays are just objects that have numeric keys and a special `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer here to accommodate the latest ECMAScript 6 standard.

Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) page for a great read with examples.

And a rather tasty caveat: this awesome new functionality will work with nearly ever iterable object! From MDN:

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects
>   (including Array, Map, Set, String, TypedArray, arguments object and
>   so on)...

So for example, you could use:

```
for (let item of myArr) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Although to super clear that you are logging an object, I would be a bit nicer to the next person to read your code by renaming "item" to "obj", producing this:

```
for (let obj of myArr) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Why rename the variable? Well, although we use the term 'item' to denote any generic item in an array, your array *only contains* objects. If you know, or expect, this array to only every contain objects, you could name the variable based on the **type** of item (i.e. an object) the array contains.

Happy coding!