# How to extract data from this JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to JSON and Jquery, and I can't find how to extract the values of ProjectCode from this JSON string.

```
[
    {
        "ProjectID": 3,
        "CLustomerCode": "XYZ001",
        "ProjectCode": "YZPROJ1",
        "Description": "Project1",
        "IssueManager": "iant",
        "NotificationToggle": false,
        "ProjectStatus": null,
        "Added": "/Date(1400701295853}/",
        "Added By": "iant",
        "Changed": "/Date(1400701295853)/",
        "Changed By": "iant"
    },
    {
        "ProjectID": 4,
        "CustomerCode": "XYZ001",
        "ProjectCode": "XYXPROJ2",
        "Description": "Projecton:Project2",
        "IssweManager": "iant",
        "NotificationToggle": false,
        "Projectstatus": null,
        "Added": "lDate(1400701317980)/",
        "AddedBy": "iant",
        "Changed": "/Date(1400701317980)/",
        "Changed By": "iant"
    }
]
```

The string above is from a variable called data that is the return value from stringify. I expected to be able to do something like

```
string proj = data[i].ProjectCode;
```

but intellisense doesn't include any of the properties.

I know very little about JSON - any help appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: well if you post an image of code, at least make the effort to indent it... Thank you!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565281/iterating-over-array-of-objects-javascript-odd-behaviour

Comment: Why why why would you use an image? Why?

Comment: Just wondering what will happen to your question once this image wouldn't be anymore online... SO is not your personal helpdesk!

Comment: Thanks for nothing wolfy

Comment: Might be a good idea to read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and lurk for awhile to figure out how things work here.  Hint: Don't use images to post code.

Comment: Thanks Rob - got that immediately after posting lol - btw you handled guiding a newbie much better which is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through each object returned in the response and get the `ProjectCode` property inside each one. Assuming the `data` variable is your JSON this should work:

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.ProjectCode);
});
```

Comment: Rory, you are a star sir - worked a treat. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use parseJSON:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON("{ 'name': 'Radiator' }");
alert(obj.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse():

```
var a; // Your JSON string
var b = JSON.parse(a);  //Your new JSON object
//You can access Project code, use index i in b[i].ProjectCode in a loop
var projectCode = b[0].ProjectCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post the raw code so its easier to visualize this stuff. Since what you are looking for is the list of `ProjectCode`s (in this case - ["XYZPROJ1", "XYZPROJ2"]).

It seems like what we have is an array or list (`[...]`) of projects. Where each project has a `ProjectID`, `CustomerCode`, `ProjectCode`, `Description` and so on...

So lets assume `data` points at this JSON blob. Here is how you would go about accessing the `ProjectCode`:

```
// Access the "i"th project code
var p_i_code = data[i].ProjectCode;

// How many projects?
var num_projects = data.length; // since data is a list of projects

// Want the list of project codes back? (I use underscore.js)
var project_codes = _.map(data, function(project) {
    return project.ProjectCode;
});
```